# Restrict a range of ports to one IP except one

Tags: iptables

Is there a way I can allow a range of ports to only be used by one IP address *but* one? Thanks.

Precisely, I want to restrict range 6011-6099 excluding 6012. The rule to restrict the range 6011-6099 is already in place.

Oh, it's worth mentioning that I'm using IPTables as the firewall. (lawl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
iptables -A INPUT-p tcp --dport 6012 -j DROP
```

Add this first to block any traffic to port `6012`.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.10.10.10 --match multiport --dport 6011:6099 -j ACCEPT
```

where `10.10.10.10` is the source IP.  This tells the system to let input coming from `10.10.10.10` destined for any port `6011-6099` through.